# memcached - how to use it for multiple records returned from single SELECT operation?

Tags: memcached

memchached is useful for caching and looking up of single independent records. For the multiple records returned from doing a SELECT operation, how could I make good use of the memcached for caching and looking up later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get you. If you use php or .net (Enyim client) you can store your result in to an object and set it in to the memcached. (Client will serialize  the object and store it in the memcached.)

Following example will store one or more records (results) returned by the db query.

```
//Init Memcache, Try avoid multiple init if possible  because this is a costly operation 
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");

mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("YOURDB");

$query = "SELECT * FROM table where `firstname`='dasun';";
$key = md5($query);
$get_result = $memcache->get($key);

if ($get_result) {
    print_r($get_result);
    echo "It's a hit! :)";
}
else {
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    print_r($row);

    // Store the result for 5 minutes
    $memcache->set($key, $row, TRUE, 300); 
    echo "Not a hit. :(";
}
```

Comment: It works great when there is no updates to the table, specifically the number of records having the same firstname. But if the table is being changed at high frequency, the cached data will be outdated in a very small time window, when that happens, would memcached still be usefu?

Comment: Another scenario, if there is another query $query2 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'lastname' = 'eddie';" which would end up returning some records that overlap with some of records returned from $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 'firstname' = 'dasun', can we still use the memcached as the way showcased above?

Comment: Personally I don't use memchaced if the table is being changed at high frequency. If you do understand about the system you might able figure out which queries are more critical than others. Most of the time users may not notice we are giving the same result for 5 minutes.

Comment: For your second comment, No you can't.

Comment: Hi dasun, For the second comment, why did you say No ? You will be storing 2 different result sets for 2 different keys ! The data might overlap and be redundant but Yes you can.

Comment: Hi Binder, I might read tom's comment incorrectly. I though he was asking a way to share common cached data on two queries.